# continue composite figure on next beamer frame

Tags: beamer, numbering

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                                                                                        
\usepackage{tikzducks}   
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % for numbering figures in beamer                                                                                                         
\usepackage{subcaption}                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                              
\title{The Title}                                                                                                                             
\author{The Author}                                                                                                                           

\begin{document}                                                                                                                           

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%                                                                                                                          
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%                                                                                                                          
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}                                                                                                                                   
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am interested to continue such a Figure consisting of 4 subfigures on the next frame, so that in slide 2

- the Figure number is the same as on slide 1
- the numbers of subfigures are c and d.

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You can use the `\ContinuedFloat` command from the `caption` package (which is already loaded by the `subcaption` package in your example)

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                                                                                        
\usepackage{tikzducks}   
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % for numbering figures in beamer                                                                                                         
\usepackage{subcaption}                                                                                                                       

\title{The Title}                                                                                                                             
\author{The Author}                                                                                                                           

\begin{document}                                                                                                                           

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%                                                                                                                          
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \begin{figure}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%                                                                                                                          
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}                                                                                                                                   
\end{document}
```

**Approach 2:**

Instead of making two separate frames, you could use use overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                                                                                        
\usepackage{tikzducks}   
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % for numbering figures in beamer                                                                                                         
\usepackage{subcaption}                                                                                                                       

\title{The Title}                                                                                                                             
\author{The Author}                                                                                                                           

\begin{document}                                                                                                                           

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{onlyenv}<1>
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
          \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%                                                                                                                          
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-b}
          \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{onlyenv}

    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-c}
          \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%                                                                                                                          
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
          \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
      \end{onlyenv}
    \caption{}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}                                                                                                                                   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 3**:

Manually change the figure counters.

```
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.45\paperwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=0.45\paperwidth]{example-image-c}%
         \setcounter{subfigure}{2}%
         \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: you meant `\setcounter{figure}{!!!!1!!!!}`

Comment: @Viesturs With `\setcounter{figure}{1}` the figure would be labelled with 2

Comment: @Viesturs indeed, you need to specify the previous value (in this case 0) because the counter is automatically increased within the `figure` environment (leading to 1 in this case). The same for the subfigure, which is set to 2 (=b) to obtain 3 (=c) after the automatic increment.